# Give the position of Null values from a table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with mixed of Null values and Non-Null values, I want position of the null value in the table for comparison before migration to other sources

```
mysql> select * from student2;
+------+---------+------------+
| id   | name    | address    |
+------+---------+------------+
|   10 | Rams    | NULL       |
|   12 | Hari    | NULL       |
|   13 | Shyam   | NULL       |
|   14 | NULL    | Hyderabad  |
|      | Revathy | Singapore  |
```

I am expecting output with only position of Null values along with the line number i.e

```
Row Number 1 Column Number 3
Row Number 2 Column Number 3
Row Number 3 Column Number 3
Row Number 4 Column Number 1
Row Number 5 Column Number 1
```

Comment: what you are trying to print ?

Comment: We cant clear what you want please describe your question.

Comment: SELECT * FROM student2 WHERE id IS NULL;

Comment: Sorry about formatting problems I want to edit like  1 3 and in next line 2 3 and in next line 3 3 and in next line 4 2 and in next line 5 1 which are null values

Comment: Is it mysql or oracle? Please edit your question's tags to have only one RDBMS

Answer (score 0):

You can get by this way-

```
mysql> select * from test;
+----+--------+--------+
| id | name   | fname  |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 | Hitesh | NULL   |
|  2 | Mundra | NULL   |
|  3 | raj    | Mundra |
|  4 | NULL   | Mundra |
+----+--------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id, if (name IS NULL,1,IF (fname is null,2,0)) as postion  from test;
+----+---------+
| id | postion |
+----+---------+
|  1 |       2 |
|  2 |       2 |
|  3 |       0 |
|  4 |       1 |
+----+---------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

for set row values you can use mysql variable.

```
     mysql> set @var=0;
    mysql> select @var:=@var+1 as row, if (name IS NULL,1,IF (fname is null,2,0)) as postion  from test;
+--------------+---------+
|          row | postion |
+--------------+---------+
|            1 |       2 |
|            2 |       2 |
|            3 |       0 |
|            4 |       1 |
+--------------+---------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
     mysql> set @var=0;
```

Comment: Thanks Hitesh. Can we print the row number instead of using existing column id and store them in a variable ?

Comment: "Row Numbers" do not exist! An RDBMS does not guarantee any physical ordering of storage.

Comment: @ramanathanArunachalam as james said row id is not exist but we can use order by id and use a variable which set count

Comment: @ramanathanArunachalam if it helps you, mark this right so it help others

Answer (score 0):

Try following,

```
Select   
    case 
        when id == 1 then 'Row Number ' + convert(varchar(10),row_id) + ' Column Number 1'
        when name == 1 then 'Row Number ' + convert(varchar(10),row_id) + ' Column Number 2'
        when address == 1 then 'Row Number ' + convert(varchar(10),row_id) + ' Column Number 3'
    end as 'Status'
from 
(
    select 
        @curRank := @curRank + 1 as row_id,
        case when id is null then 1 else 0 end as id, 
        case when name is null then 1 else 0 end as name,
        case when address is null then 1 else 0 end as address
    from student2, (SELECT @curRank := 0)
) T
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this query can help you:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM student2 si
        WHERE si.id <= s.id) As RowNo,
       CASE WHEN s.name IS NULL THEN 1
            WHEN s.address IS NULL THEN 2
       END As ColumnNo
FROM student2 s
WHERE COALESCE(s.name, s.address, '0') <> '0'
```